# changing grub background colour in Freya

Tags: grub

I've been trying to change the grub (menu) background colour. No matter what I try the black grub menu will remain.

I've changed the plymouth theme elementary.grub file. Here are the contents of that file:

```
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
```

This is copied from my Ubuntu 15.10 box where it works fine and any changes I do in the rgb value take effect.

I've tried a 3 variable rgb option as well (44,0,30) to no avail. Adding a space between the last value and the semi-colon does not make any difference.

Comment: you mean the method working fine in Ubuntu but not in elementary, right?

Comment: That is what I mean, yes. Editing the *.grub file in Ubuntu 15.10 works fine. Updating it in Elementary does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Use [grub-customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer)

Download [latest version](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer/4.0/4.0.6/+download/grub-customizer_4.0.6.tar.gz) and install.

Or This PPA contains the latest release of Grub Customizer

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Open `grub-customizer` --> Appearence settings

[image: Imgur]

**Note**: After customizing  don't forget to **save** changes.

Comment: The background image doesn't work.

Comment: @JulianLai Open new question,  :)

Comment: I appreciate that I might be able to do it with this application. However, it should be possible by changing the file manually as well.

Answer (score 1):

After editing `elementary.grub` you need to run `update-grub` to regenerate `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` with the new theme.

Specifically, it runs the script `/etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme` and picks up the default plymouth theme defined in `/lib/plymouth/themes/default.grub`.

If `elementary.grub` is not already your default theme, select it with `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`.